# Ruby on rails, split a big form into separate smaller forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Could not find the answer to the question on how to split forms in rails in multiple smaller forms.

Say you have a big form with

- firstname
- lastname
- gender
- age
- email
- country
- city
- state

I have a `validate_presence` for all these fields. So when I create several forms like:

```
= simple_form_for @profile, :wrapper => :inline do |f|

  = f.label "firstname"
  = f.select :firstname
```

*without* all the values from the top list (first name,last name,etc) I get errors because the splitter form does not contain those values and they need to be present at first to make this work at all.

What would be a good way to have several forms but with only a portion of the values and update them without getting the issue described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the ability to update pieces of the model then you need to split the validations into pieces as well.

One way to do it is to have a virtual attribute in your model that gets set by a hidden field in each form. E.g you may have a form:

```
= simple_form_for @profile, :wrapper => :inline do |f|
  = f.hidden :form, :input_html => {:value => 'names'} 
  = f.label "firstname"
  = f.select :firstname
```

Then in your model:

```
class Profile
  attr_accessor :form

  validates :firstname, :presence => true, :if => lambda { |o| o.form == "names" }
end
```

The validation will run only if the change was submitted from the right form.

Check out conditional validation guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation for more details.

Other way is a multistep form as suggested by apneadiving: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms This uses the same technique as in the first example by having a current_step attribute, but the progression is linear.

Comment: Thx, for simple_form we need to use   =f.hidden_field :title, :value => "basics" instead. However after modifying the changes suggested I seems to have no validation occur when values are empty it just proceeds updating the profile. have to look into it further but this is at least on the right track thx, I'm using rails 3.1 maybe therefore I need other syntax

Comment: Make sure "form" parameter is passed to the model for assignment.

Comment: I have   attr_accessor :form and searched about passing parameters to the model and attr_accessor comesup. What exactly do you mean with "Make sure "form" parameter is passed to the model for assignment" thx

Comment: I meant you should check if "form" attribute on the model is actually set. Simple `puts` in the lambda above can easily show that.

If the "form" attribute isn't set, well, you have to figure out why. It depends on how your controller looks like and what other code is in your model. E.g. if controller uses mass assingment (e.g. assign_attributes) you'll also need `attr_accessible` (which isn't the same as `attr_accessor`) in your model. Read http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible for details on that.

Comment: I missed a stupid typo I copied example :=f.hidden_field :title, :value => "basics" wich should have been :form of course, your example worked great after that

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a multi step form I guess.

Look at [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms), you'll find conditional validations which are the way to proceed.

Comment: Found it already, this is multistep needed speration without a step process but thx for pointing out